# Python. How do I make a list of small portions of a bigger list?

Tags: python, list

```
for word in list6:
    if word = "TRUMP":
```

So, I have a list of every word in a debate transcript. When Trump speaks, it starts with "TRUMP". I need to take his words and put them into a seperate list. If the word in list6 is "TRUMP", then I need to put everything into a list until it says another person's name. He speaks more than once.

I just need help completing this loop.

Comment: Why not use dictionaries? (Key-Value solutions?) That way, you can put each candidate's speech within the designated key (Key's being Trump, Ted, Kiasch, etc)

Comment: I will be eventually taking everything said by Trump into a dictionary and finding how often he uses words.

Comment: Can you expand your example. So far, what you provided is too minimal to explore what's exactly needed. If you can state your problem into bullet points, and also give example of what the output would look like given the input

Comment: I need to take a list and split it into the words that people said.

Comment: at points in the list, names are said in all caps ex. TRUMP CLINTON KASICH

Comment: I need to make lists of the words that each person said.

Comment: I need a for loop to go through each word until I find the right name, and then once I find that name, I put every word after it into a list until another name comes up. Then, I will stop until I find the same name again. Then ill append everything that person said into that same list.

Comment: How would you handle situations where if a candidate mentions someone else's name? What does the input look like?

Comment: It won't be in all caps if they say another name.

Comment: ex. ["TRUMP","I","am","Donald",Trump","CLINTON",,"I","am","not","Donald",Trump","TRUMP","I","should","be","president"]

Answer (score 2):

```
list6 = ['TRUMP','I','am','good', 'HILLARY','I','am','good','too','TRUMP','But','How?']
person_words = {'TRUMP':[], 'HILLARY':[]}

person_names = person_words.keys()

one_person_onetime_words = []

for word in list6:
    if word in person_names:
        if len(one_person_onetime_words):
            person_words[this_person].append(one_person_onetime_words)
            one_person_onetime_words = []
        this_person = word
    else:
        one_person_onetime_words.append(word)

person_words[this_person].append(one_person_onetime_words)

print person_words
```

Gives

```
{'HILLARY': [['I', 'am', 'good', 'too']], 'TRUMP': [['I', 'am', 'good'], ['But', 'How?']]}
```

So, this in a single shot gives all the different talks by all the persons.

As mentioned by you in the comments to your question, if you want to get one person's words only you can use the following:

```
from copy import copy

list6 = ['TRUMP','I','am','good', 'HILLARY','I','am','good','too','TRUMP','But','How?']
person_words = []
all_persons = ['TRUMP', 'HILLARY']
person_looking_for = 'TRUMP'

filter_out_persons = copy(all_persons)
filter_out_persons.remove(person_looking_for)

person_onetime_words = []

capture_words = False
for word in list6:
    if word == person_looking_for:
        capture_words = True
        if len(person_onetime_words):
            person_words.append(person_onetime_words)
            person_onetime_words = []
    elif word not in filter_out_persons and capture_words:
        person_onetime_words.append(word)
    else:
        capture_words = False

person_words.append(person_onetime_words)
print "{}'s words".format(person_looking_for)
print person_words
```

That gives

```
TRUMP's words
[['I', 'am', 'good'], ['But', 'How?']]
```

And, the following will give a dictionary with words as keys and the value will be a dictionary again with frequency of each person for that word.

```
import pprint

list6 = ['TRUMP','I','am','good', 'HILLARY','I','am','good','too','TRUMP','But','How?']

person_names = ['TRUMP','HILLARY']

word_frequency = {}
for word in list6:
    if word in person_names:
        person = word
    else:
        word = word.lower()
        if word in word_frequency:
            if person in word_frequency[word]:
                word_frequency[word][person] += 1
            else:
                word_frequency[word][person] = 1
        else:
            word_frequency[word] = {person: 1}

pprint.pprint(word_frequency)
```

Gives

```
{'am': {'HILLARY': 1, 'TRUMP': 1},
 'but': {'TRUMP': 1},
 'good': {'HILLARY': 1, 'TRUMP': 1},
 'how?': {'TRUMP': 1},
 'i': {'HILLARY': 1, 'TRUMP': 1},
 'too': {'HILLARY': 1}}
```

Comment: That helps a lot, but I need it in a list form. I will be taking the lists and then putting them in a dictionary. the key will be the words spoken and the value will be how frequent the words were said.

Comment: Please see my changes to the answer.  Added another snippet which will give you the words of only one person of your choice as a list of lists.

Comment: Made a change in the 2nd snippet to check length of list before appending.  This should now cover more edge cases.

Comment: @RyanAckerman added 3rd snippet, which should give you the end result  of dictionary with word as key and frequency by each person for that word.